# How can I obtain the data of how many memory references are symbolized by IDA-Pro?

Tags: ida, symbols

We all know that in typical programs, there exist some references.

[image]

When compiling, linker will translate all the memory references into **concrete memory addresses** during the symbol relocation step. And by doing some quick experiments (IDA-Pro 6.4), I notice that IDA-Pro can help to lift these memory addresses back into symbols.

However, I found that the symbolization functionality of IDA-Pro can be mislead by some cases. So what I am interested is to calculate how many references have been recovered by IDA-Pro. I am asking that is there anyway to obtain the information of **"how many memory references are recovered by IDA-Pro?"**

Thanks @Jason a lot for his answer, but what I am trying to do is not collect all the labels. Here is an example:

[image]

Please pay attention to the symbol `sub_80484AE` in address `0x804a020`. Note that the 4 byte data `0x08, 0x04, 0x84, 0xae` in porocessed binary are considered as a symbol, as it is equal to the beginning address of function `sub_80484AE`. This is true. However, as no instruction refers to the address `0x804A020`, so there is no `name` in address `0x804a020`.

What I want to collect is all the symbols with its corresponding address, for example, in the above case, I need to collect this

```
0x804a018 : sub_804847b
0x804a01dc : _strchr
0x804a020 : sub_80484AE
```

Am I clear enough? I really appreciate if anyone can give me some help! Thank you a lot!!

----------------------------------------------- update ---------------------------------------

Am I still not clear enough?

Let me put it in this way. Can I obtain all the symbol information which used to be resolved by linker? Say, in the picture I updated, during compiling linker resolved three symbols, at memory address 0x804a018, 0x804a01dc, 0x804a020. IDA-Pro recovers some of these information. So I want to collect all the IDA recovered symbol information (this information could be **function name**, or it could be **an entry of jump table**, or it could be a **jump destination**, as I draw in the picture).

Note that I want to recover the information in a format that each resolved symbol together with the memory address. For example in the picture, it should be:

```
0x804a018 : sub_804847b
0x804a01dc : _strchr
0x804a020 : sub_80484AE
```

I am thinking to traverse all the memory address of a binary, and check each the oprend of instruction (or content if it is in the data section), to see whether it is a recovered symbol or not. If so, I will store this symbol together with this instruction (or data)'s memory address.

But basically how to check whether a oprend in a instruction is a symbol?

Comment: Sorry for the off topic, may I ask what did you use to create the function graph?

Comment: @DominikAntal, I use tiKz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how many addresses have names.

For example, in the following snippet, two of the addresses in the snippet have names (`loc_4385E4` and `dword_4385F8`), since both are cross-referenced from other addresses:

```
.text:004385E4 loc_4385E4:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_4254E0+1C0j
.text:004385E4                                         ; CODE XREF: sub_4254E0+1E6j
.text:004385E4                 push    ecx
.text:004385E5                 push    ecx
.text:004385E6                 push    0Eh
.text:004385E8                 pop     edx
.text:004385E9                 mov     ecx, offset dword_438618
.text:004385EE                 call    sub_4421A7
.text:004385F3                 jmp     loc_4256A6
.text:004385F3 ; END OF FUNCTION CHUNK FOR sub_4254E0
.text:004385F3 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:004385F8 dword_4385F8    dd 1000000Ah, 80204h, 10000h, 80010000h
.text:004385F8                                         ; DATA XREF: sub_4254E0+13092o
```

You can use the IDC script below to count all named addresses in your disassembly:

```
auto ea;
auto names = 0;

for (ea = BeginEA(); ea != BADADDR; ea = NextNotTail(ea))
{
    if (Name(ea) != "")
    {
        names++;
    }
}

Message("%d named addresses found.\n", names);
```

​

***Edit***

The change you made to your original question now makes it sounds like you want to capture all function names. To do this, open the Functions window (in the menubar: *View* → *Open subviews* → *Functions*), right-click in the Functions window, and choose *Copy all*. You can now paste the list of function names into a text editor or spreadsheet.

Comment: Hello Jason, thank you for your answer. I haven't tested yet, but in the above case, what if `dword_4385F8` is a function pointer array? I want to calculate, say, in the array, how many entries (memory addresses) have been symbolized by IDA-Pro.

Comment: Sum up the labels could be a subset of all the symbolized references, as there could be multiple references, say, data to code references, that points to the same function.

Comment: "how many entries (memory addresses) have been symbolized by IDA-Pro." -- If an entry is directly cross-referenced then IDA will give it a name and the script above will include it in the count.

Comment: Hello Jason, I updated my question. Would you mind to take a look? :-) Am I clear now?

Comment: Answer updated.